# Database table UPDATE form doesn´t work

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have read like 10 tutorials on how to update database info, I have tried at least 3 different ways, but nothing works. This code below always echo "Success", though it doesn´t update if I check the database.

```
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
$dbhost = 'host';
$dbuser = 'user';
$dbpass = 'password';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$name= $_POST['name'];

$sql = "UPDATE table SET name='$name' WHERE id='$id'";

mysql_select_db('my_db');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Success">";
mysql_close($conn);
}
else
{
  include"db.inc.php";
   $id = $_GET["id"];
   $order = "SELECT * FROM table where id='$id'";
   $result = mysql_query($order);
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

}
    ?>
<form id="update" name="update" method="post" role="form" action="">
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="<? echo "$row[name]"?>" />
<input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Save">
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

I don´t know what I am doing wrong...any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: I considered your comments and edited my code

```
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
$dbhost = 'host';
$dbuser = 'user';
$dbpass = 'password';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$name= $_POST['name'];

mysql_select_db('my_db'); 
$sql = "UPDATE table SET name='$name' WHERE id='$id'";


$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
else{
echo "Success";}

mysql_close($conn);
}
else
{
  include"db.inc.php";
   $id = $_GET["id"];
   $order = "SELECT * FROM table where id='$id'";
   $result = mysql_query($order);
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

}
    ?>
<form id="update" name="update" method="post" role="form" action="">
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="<? echo "$row[name]"?>" />
<input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Save">
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

I get $id variable through url like edit-form.php?id=123
This code above does exactly the same that the first one, echoes Success and do nothing with database info.

EDIT:
Ok, I think it might me solved. I used the very first version of my code (the first one here) and I put

```
$id = $_GET["id"];
```

above

```
$name= $_POST['name'];
```

It seems to work.

Comment: Where are you defining `$id` in the POST case?

Comment: At least you have a misplaced quote in echo "Success">";
Furthermore look into PDO instead of your current code style: This is easy to hack using sql injection.

Comment: Did you really name your table table?Also you should select the db before any query

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** `$_GET` values are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) because have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) here.

Comment: And the script is evaluated in order up-down,so your $_POST is empty since your form is parsed at the end

Answer (score 2):

I hope these 5 points will help you

1. Your `echo "Success">";` is not in the conditional braces. No matter if the data gets update or not it will show success always
2. mysql_select_db and mysql_query are all depreciated. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead try using `mysqli_select_db` ? It should be before the query. **This is reason why the SQL is not updating** . Try in this sequence

   `mysqli_select_db($conn,'my_db');
   $sql = "UPDATE table SET name='$name' WHERE id='$id'";`

   For reference http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php

   OR
3. You may like to do it in one line

   `$conn = mysqli_connect("host","user","password","my_db") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($conn ));`
4. Are you getting the correct value of `$id` in `WHERE id='$id'`. As I see `$id = $_GET["id"];` is after the SQL. For debugging print the query in browser, see if you are getting the right value

Comment: 1 & 2 are proper comments (and no answer), 3 .. `mysql_select_db()` is literally the line before the query

Comment: mysqli_select_db($conn,'my_db'); I tried this and getting error Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in edit_form.php on line 75 Could not update data: No database selected

Comment: see mysqli_select_db() in manual. Add the missing connection parameter

Comment: I tried also the one line option and get another error: Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, object given in edit_form.php on line 71

Comment: when using the one liner, try this `$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE table SET name='$name' WHERE id='$id'");`

Comment: Yes, I am getting the right value of $id. Now I have some other error: Could not update data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'table SET name='Chloe' WHERE id=''' at line 1

Comment: As expected, `id is NULL` because  `$id = $_GET["id"];` should be before the update query.

Comment: I put it above update query and have same error, just WHERE id="123"

Comment: So if you are printing the query in browser you get `UPDATE table SET name='Chloe' WHERE id=123;` . If you get this you should never get any syntax error. Try to get this printed in browser. And your are done. By the way, Is the name of your table-name `'TABLE'` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the id in as well. If you dont want to make it visible to the user you could put it in as a hidden field so your form would be:

```
<form id="update" name="update" method="post" role="form" action="">
<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="<? echo "$row[id]"?>" />
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="<? echo "$row[name]"?>" />
<input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Save">
```

Comment: Done, but no changes...still same result

Comment: @user3346354 Did you also add `$id = $_POST['id']` to your script (just above where you do the same for `name`)?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think it might me solved. I used the very first version of my code (the first one here) and I put

```
$id = $_GET["id"];
```

above

```
$name= $_POST['name'];
```

It seems to work. Thanks everyone for their posts!